# Resample with xarray gives back: TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I'm trying to do a couple of calculations using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ds1 = xr.open_mfdataset('HIST/*nc')

ds1 = ds1.loc[dict(time=slice('1996-01-01','2005-12-31'))]

ds1 = ds1.resample(time='24H').sum('time')

ds_yrmax1 = ds1.resample(time='AS').max('time')
```

The complete error I get back is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GFDL-CM3_interp_hist.py", line 29, in <module>
 ds2 = ds2.resample(time='D').sum('time')
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/common.py", line 53, in wrapped_func
 **kwargs)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/resample.py", line 303, in reduce
 func, self._dim, keep_attrs, **kwargs)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/groupby.py", line 654, in reduce
 return self.apply(reduce_dataset)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/resample.py", line 272, in apply
 combined = self._combine(applied)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/groupby.py", line 619, in _combine
 combined = self._maybe_restore_empty_groups(combined)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/groupby.py", line 342, in _maybe_restore_empty_groups
 combined = combined.reindex(**indexers)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1767, in reindex
 tolerance, copy=copy)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/alignment.py", line 374, in reindex_variables
 new_var = var._getitem_with_mask(key)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/variable.py", line 659, in _getitem_with_mask
 data = duck_array_ops.where(mask, fill_value, data)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/duck_array_ops.py", line 164, in where
 return _where(condition, *as_shared_dtype([x, y]))
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/duck_array_ops.py", line 107, in as_shared_dtype
 out_type = dtypes.result_type(*arrays)
File "/opt/apps/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/xarray/core/dtypes.py", line 186, in result_type
 return np.result_type(*arrays_and_dtypes)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

However, when I get rid of the line that seems to be causing the problems 
(`ds1 = ds1.resample(time='24H').sum('time')`), it runs fine and I don't get any other errors when trying to resample.

This made me really confused and I'm not sure where the problem is. The fact it works fine when the code is changed a little bit makes me think something is going wrong specifically with taking the sum rather than an issue with my data or the resampling itself. I wasn't sure though and have no idea how to fix.

**Edit 1: Data Details**

The data is 3-hrly rainfall data with a shape `(10,90,144)`. I'm trying to find the daily total and then the maximum daily value for each year.

Here is the complete information about `ds1` when printed if that also helps.(*prior to slice):

```
Dimensions:     (bnds: 2, lat: 90, lon: 144, time: 61320)
Coordinates:
  * lat         (lat) float64 -89.0 -87.0 -85.0 -83.0 -81.0 -79.0 -77.0 ...
  * lon         (lon) float64 1.25 3.75 6.25 8.75 11.25 13.75 16.25 18.75 ...
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1985-01-01T01:30:00 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds   (time, bnds) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(61320, 2), chunksize=(14600, 2)>
    lat_bnds    (time, lat, bnds) float64 dask.array<shape=(61320, 90, 2), chunksize=(14600, 90, 2)>
    lon_bnds    (time, lon, bnds) float64 dask.array<shape=(61320, 144, 2), chunksize=(14600, 144, 2)>
    pr          (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(61320, 90, 144), chunksize=(14600, 90, 144)>
    average_T1  (time) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(61320,), chunksize=(14600,)>
    average_T2  (time) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(61320,), chunksize=(14600,)>
    average_DT  (time) timedelta64[ns] dask.array<shape=(61320,), chunksize=(14600,)>
Attributes:
    title:                  NOAA GFDL GFDL-CM3, historical (run 1) experiment...
    institute_id:           NOAA GFDL
    source:                 GFDL-CM3 2010 atmosphere: AM3 (AM3p9,C48L48); sea...
    contact:                gfdl.climate.model.info@noaa.gov
    project_id:             CMIP5
    table_id:               Table 3hr (31 Jan 2011)
    experiment_id:          historical
    realization:            1
    modeling_realm:         atmos
    tracking_id:            e282fe4d-65a5-446f-8fc5-3cee468e6c71
    Conventions:            CF-1.4
    references:             The GFDL Data Portal (http://nomads.gfdl.noaa.gov...
    comment:                GFDL experiment name: CM3Z_D1_1860-2005_AllForc_H...
    gfdl_experiment_name:   CM3Z_D1_1860-2005_AllForc_H1
    creation_date:          2012-02-21T21:23:03Z
    model_id:               GFDL-CM3
    branch_time:            0.0
    experiment:             historical
    forcing:                GHG,SA,Oz,LU,Sl,Vl,SS,BC,MD,OC (GHG includes CO2,...
    frequency:              3hr
    initialization_method:  1
    parent_experiment_id:   piControl
    physics_version:        1
    product:                output1
    institution:            NOAA GFDL(201 Forrestal Rd, Princeton, NJ, 08540)
    history:                File was processed by fremetar (GFDL analog of CM...
    parent_experiment_rip:  r1i1p1
    institution_id:         NOAA GFDL(201 Forrestal Rd, Princeton, NJ, 08540)
```

Comment: Can you provide a description of the dataset? e.g. `print(ds1)`. Better yet would be a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't require downloading your dataset.

Comment: I added a bit more info. about the data. Hopefully that helps. I'm not sure if I could make a better example to use because this method I'm using works fine for other data sets (model data) I'm using, but does not work for this particular one in this particular instance with `ds1 = ds1.resample(time='24H').sum('time')`

Comment: My guess is that taking the sum of the datetime objects you have in your dataset is not a valid operation. How does `ds1['pr'].resample(time='24H').sum('time')` work?

Comment: That seems to fix things! Thanks!